# Expose internal container IP address to host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to expose the internal IP address of a docker container to host machine without port mapping, while options such as `--ip` exist, I do not want to manually set the IP, I want the docker container to expose whatever IP address it gets to the host.

Is there a way to let the docker container automatically redirect its assigned IP to host? The number of containers are not defined, the application auto-scales so there might be a new container at any given moment and I don't want to assign it manually.

All I found researching the topic is the other way around where they expose the host to the container or unanswered questions/outdated methods.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu, If you're using default networking, use the static IP `172.17.0.1`, which will you have to specify the port to connect to the service you want.

If you are using Docker Desktop for Windows, `host.docker.internal` will always be your default docker network.

And If you want, You can run the entire application over your own made up Network,

1. Creating your `mynetowrk` at `10.1.0.5/16`

```
docker network create --subnet=10.1.0.5/16 mynetwork
```

2. run the container with IP in the range of the subnet

```
docker run --net mynetwork --ip 10.1.0.5 -d -p 8080:80 hello-world
```

And this will always be accessible at `10.1.0.5:8080`

And if you are using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network) which is probably the case , You need to add the network and link with services

```yaml
services:
  # ...
networks:
  default:
    name: mynetwork
    external: true
```

UPDATE

If you are trying to get the static IP of contianers in a docker compose , Here is what You can do.

1. Confidure network in `docker-compose.yaml`

```
networks:
  mynetwork:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24
```

2. Add `ipv4_address` is network section at services like the following

```
services:
    redis:
        image: redis:latest
        networks:
            frontend:
                ipv4_address: 172.20.0.1
```

this will case your service to be accessible at `172.20.0.1` but I really don't recommend doing that, as you can expose other services to another port.

Comment: Each container I'm running is running on the same port, but each container has its own IP address so there's no conflict in their network, the issue is I want the automatically assigned IP by docker to the container to be accessed through the host automatically, as in if my container is running on `172.17.0.1` then I could ping that address directly from the host without any port forwarding or the `--ip` command.